# How can I get an array to an NSManagedObject

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am sorry if I put out silly questions but I am new to Swift. I am building an app and so far it goes quite well. But now I want to delete some rows from my tableview which gets feeded from an Array with Strings. And then I want to save/fetch that using core data. I believe I have the code for it but the problem is that I am trying to save an array full of Strings. so I get error message saying: Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'NSManagedObject'. And therefore I am wondering, how can I solve this? Is there any way to "add those Strings to an NSManagedObject somehow?

Here are my code:

the array :
[image]

and here are the code:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData




class tableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return (List.count)

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) ->     UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    cell.textLabel?.text = List.self[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.white
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear




    return(cell)

}

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle:     UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as!     AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

        if editingStyle == .delete{
            let rows = List[indexPath.row]
            context.delete(rows)
            (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).saveContext()

            do{
                List = try context.fetch(MealsMenu.fetchRequest()) as! [String]
            }
            catch{
                print(error)
            }
        }
        myTableView.reloadData()

}





@IBOutlet weak var myTableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    myTableView.reloadData()
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    CoredataClass.saveItems()
    CoredataClass.loadData()
}

}
```

Comment: You should have an array of `NSManagedObject`, where the string is a property of that object.  Then, when you remove a row, you remove `delete` the object from Core Data.  For something like this you probably want to use a `NSFetchedResultsController` - It makes it simpler to handle Core Data events while updating your tableview.

Comment: Think of NSManagedObject’s as rows in a spreadsheet. Your string Array would be one of the columns in that spreadsheet. Seek a basic coredata tutorial or at leastlook at how the template Xcode app does this.

Comment: Thanks! That sounds fair! I Will have a look Into coredatacontroller. Definitely. May I ask how a NSManagedObject which includes an array could look like?

Comment: Core data is a database of sorts. You wouldn’t normally have an collection embedded in a managed object. If you needed an array stored  you would construct a one to many relationship to other entities. However what you are describing in your question is answered by Alejandro.  Seriously grab a short tutorial on coredata, it’ll be an hour well spent.

Comment: Hi, thanks. You are definitely right in that and I will pick up some tutorials. I have already seen some actually but it takes some time to fully understand :) thanks for your answers anyway...

Answer (score 3):

You will need to create a function like this

Imagine that your Entity is `Recipe` which has an string attribute `recipeName` which contains the name of the recipe.

```
func fetchPersistentData() -> [String] {


    var recipes = [String]()

    guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {

        return recipes
    }

    let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Recipe>(entityName: "Recipe")

    do {
        let fetchedResults = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)

        if fetchedResults.count > 0 {

            recipes = fetchedResults.map { ("\($0.recipeName)")}

            return recipes
        }

    } catch let error as NSError {
        // Wrong handling
        print(error.description)
    }

    return recipes
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, I will try this asap. Thanks

Comment: I managed to implement this code now, with my current elements in it. That made it I lost some other lines in the code later, which is all logical. The thing is that, I had this array (the one you have called "recipes" as a global string earlier, and then later in the code I called for that to update a tableview by adding "List.count". But now, since this array are inside this function, how can I now reach it?

Comment: By use "List" I get told that it is an "unused identifier", which I do understand. I tried "fetchPersistentData.List" and just "fetchPersistentData()" but I am really taking chances here =). I am sorry for probably ask such obvious questions, but I am new to swift and I am learning by doing tutorials, and some reading/challenges and also by trial and error with in my own apps. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Good to hear, hope my approach helped you in some way :)